# Ubuntu apt-get update error

Tags: 14.04, updates

When executing `sudo apt-get update` I get the following error

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-es_ES                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-es                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-es_ES                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-es                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-es_ES                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-es                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-es_ES                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-es                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Descargados 2.981 kB en 22seg. (131 kB/s)                                      
W: Imposible obtener http://ppa.launchpad.net/jconti/gnome3/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Imposible obtener http://ppa.launchpad.net/jconti/gnome3/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Algunos archivos de índice fallaron al descargar. Se han ignorado, o se han utilizado unos antiguos en su lugar
```

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: these are ppas that aren't working you can try this
http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:jconti/gnome3`

You have a PPA included in your apt-sources list which does not contain a package for your distribution ([trusty](https://launchpad.net/~jconti/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3/+packages)), hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:jconti/gnome3
```

Comment: Thank I ran it, but now I get the following error: http://pastebin.com/WJ57FEdH

Comment: paste output of this: ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d and cat /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6GaeRM5d

Comment: Try this, go to /etc/apt/source.list.d and execute sudo chmod -r google* we will see if it solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove the sources in the /etc/apt/sources.list and then the Update should work

Comment: That's doing it the hard way. The easy way to do it is to run: `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:jconti/gnome3`

Comment: Yea but the "hard way"  works every time and he knows what he had done